# openTK vs openCL.NET

Tags: .net, gpgpu, opentk, opencl.net

I am getting started with openCL on .NET. How is openTK compared to openCL.NET - which is better?

Answer (score 3):

Neither, they're not to be compared. Apples and oranges and stuff like that :)

OpenTK is a C# interface to OpenGL.
OpenCL.Net is a C# interface to OpenCL.

OpenGL is OpenGL, built for one purpose.
OpenCL is OpenCL, built for another purpose.

OpenTK has OpenCL.Net bindings, so you can actually use OpenCL with OpenTK.

Comment: The OpenCL bindings were moved from OpenTK to Cloo (http://sourceforge.net/projects/cloo/), as that would allow both projects to be more flexible and develop faster. Other than that, you are pretty much spot on.